# Using pipeable operators and subscribing to only "inner" observable

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Assume you have the following code:

```
protected _state = new ReplaySubject<CartState>();

getTransformedState(id: number) {
    return this._state.pipe(map(({ items }) => items[id]));
}
```

And im getting this transformed Observable in another component, and I subscribe to it.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.cart.getTransformedState(this.product.id).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((item) => {})
}
```

Diving into Rxjs documentation we can see that transforming one Observable with usage of pipeable operators and then subscribing to the 'outcome' observable also subscribes to 'origin' observable.

> An Pipeable Operator is essentially a pure function which takes one Observable as input and generates another Observable as output. **Subscribing to the output Observable will also subscribe to the input Observable.**

My question arise from unit test provided in the project that is failing to complete

```
it('should have one subscription for product cart item', async(() => {
    const mockSubject = ServiceMock.getItemUpdates(MockProduct);

    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(mockSubject['observers'].length).toEqual(1);
}));
```

Comment: I think this is a bad unit test because you are trying to verify the internal functionality of a third party library. It offers no verification of the intended functionality of the source code being tested. You should test the service and your source code and assume RxJs works as intended. Otherwise you are doing an integration test and there are better tools for those kinds of tests.

Comment: @cgTag unit test was provided in coding exercise for middle angular position. To be fair im not in the 'unit testing' basket just yet (although my mentality and attitude towards unit testing is shifting), that's why I never questioned the unit test itself. Just tried to find a solution.